# Почему в запросе SQL не видна таблица созданная в пакете?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, типы-данных, package

Я создал два типа - `t_shots` и `tab_shots` вот таким кодом:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_shots IS OBJECT (
    name varchar2(50), 
    x number(3,0), 
    y number(3,0));

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_shots IS TABLE OF t_shots;
```

Добавил переменную `tabl_shots` в пакет:

```
create or replace PACKAGE shots_pack AS
    tabl_shots tab_shots := tab_shots();
end shots_pack;
```

И хочу вывести переменную `tabl_shots` из пакета с помощью запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM shots_pack.tabl_shots;
```

Как мне кажется, если данных в этой таблице нет, значит должно вывестись:

> no data found

Но мне выводится такая ошибка:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Почему возникает эта ошибка и как её исправить?

Comment: Вот это предложение _В теле пакета tab_shots я её тоже на всякий случай объявил_ вместе с кодом вы можете спокойно убрать из вопроса. Оно никаким образом  к текушему вопросу не относится.

Comment: Упомянутый в комментарии выше фрагмент я удалил из вопроса. Вы как автор вопроса можете всегда вернуть его обратно, если считаете, что он всё таки имеет отношение к вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напрямую нельзя обратится в SQL запросе к коллекции объявленной в пакете.

Объявите табличную функцию возвращающую коллекцию. Вот так:

```sql
create or replace package shots_pack as
    function getShots return tab_shots pipelined;
end shots_pack;
/
create or replace package body shots_pack as
    tabl_shots tab_shots := tab_shots();
    function getShots return tab_shots pipelined is
    begin 
        for i in 1..shots_pack.tabl_shots.count loop
            pipe row (shots_pack.tabl_shots(i));
        end loop;
        return;
    end getShots;
end shots_pack;
/

select * from shots_pack.getShots();
```

Результат:

> no rows selected

Comment: Большое спасибо вам за ответ. Задам вопрос. Скажите пожалуйста, что в данном случае в объявлении функции означает pipelined?

Comment: "Трубная" - итерация между pl/sql и sql движками будет асинхронной, т.е. один будет помещать запись за записью в pipe, другой забирать по необходимости. Вы можете и без piplined обойтись, но так будет лучше.